# Ansible Zypper module error when I try to update packages

Tags: linux, ansible, opensuse, suse

Good day all!

I have written a very simple Ansible Role to update all packages to Suse Leap 15.2:

```
- name: All packages updated
  package:
    name: "*"
    state: latest
```

but it seems that the Zypper module has a problem with it:

```
TASK [system_update : All packages updated] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/merlin/ansible-kt-linux/roles/system_update/tasks/main.yml:10
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: merlin
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~merlin && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/merlin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1617094154.778992-48329012899811 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1617094154.778992-48329012899811="` echo /home/merlin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1617094154.778992-48329012899811 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/modules/packaging/os/zypper.py
<localhost> PUT /home/merlin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-5239dx5tukgw/tmpvf5upp37 TO /home/merlin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1617094154.778992-48329012899811/AnsiballZ_zypper.py
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/merlin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1617094154.778992-48329012899811/ /home/merlin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1617094154.778992-48329012899811/AnsiballZ_zypper.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-qfmrjmpwqhyapufsdqunaohtmlxjucdk ; /usr/bin/python /home/merlin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1617094154.778992-48329012899811/AnsiballZ_zypper.py'"'"' && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /home/merlin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1617094154.778992-48329012899811/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/merlin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1617094154.778992-48329012899811/AnsiballZ_zypper.py", line 102, in <module>
    _ansiballz_main()
  File "/home/merlin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1617094154.778992-48329012899811/AnsiballZ_zypper.py", line 94, in _ansiballz_main
    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
  File "/home/merlin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1617094154.778992-48329012899811/AnsiballZ_zypper.py", line 40, in invoke_module
    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible.modules.packaging.os.zypper', init_globals=None, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 188, in run_module
    fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 82, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/tmp/ansible_zypper_payload_jYlnfB/ansible_zypper_payload.zip/ansible/modules/packaging/os/zypper.py", line 195, in <module>
ImportError: No module named xml
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/home/merlin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1617094154.778992-48329012899811/AnsiballZ_zypper.py\", line 102, in <module>\n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/home/merlin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1617094154.778992-48329012899811/AnsiballZ_zypper.py\", line 94, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/home/merlin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1617094154.778992-48329012899811/AnsiballZ_zypper.py\", line 40, in invoke_module\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible.modules.packaging.os.zypper', init_globals=None, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 188, in run_module\n    fname, loader, pkg_name)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 82, in _run_module_code\n    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 72, in _run_code\n    exec code in run_globals\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_zypper_payload_jYlnfB/ansible_zypper_payload.zip/ansible/modules/packaging/os/zypper.py\", line 195, in <module>\nImportError: No module named xml\n",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

unfortunately I can't read from this what exactly the problem is. Do any of you know the problem?

Comment: `ImportError: No module named xml` you are missing xml python module. install it.

Comment: okay, one second after i posted this i saw it :D

anyway thanks for the answer!

Comment: another problem: is there an alternate way to install python-xml without using zypper on Suse?

Comment: There is `rpm`, there is `pip`. Still, use `zypper`.

Comment: i solved it by add a shell command to install it with zypper. i tried to download the rpm and install it with the yum module but it still takes zypper.

Answer (score 1):

solved it with shell:

```
- name: "Install python-xml on Suse"
  shell: zypper -n install python-xml
```